# How many levels of thread priorities are there?

Tags: pthreads, posix

I was wondering how many levels of thread priorities are there?. Is it dependent on the OS that uses posix ?

Comment: please accept the answer as the solution by clicking the tick/check mark against the answer. It helps people know that this is solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the implementation used by your OS.  You should use

[int sched_get_priority_min(int policy);](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/sched_get_priority_max.html)

[int sched_get_priority_max(int policy);](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/sched_get_priority_max.html)

to find the range for a particular scheduling policy on your platform.

Comment: Thanks Duck , and I am assuming that the most used scheduling policies are FIFO and RR and Other like in the answer DheeB gave above . Is that correct?

Comment: Yes I think those are by far the most common though there are other policies (e.g. SCHED_SPORADIC) as well. Different ways to split the atom so to speak.

Answer (score 1):

## Depends on Schedule Policy

Here are the various values:
[image: pthread priority limits]

[source](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_MRG/1.3/html/Realtime_Reference_Guide/chap-Realtime_Reference_Guide-Priorities_and_policies.html)

Comment: Thanks Dheeb !This info gave me a lot of insight on scheduling policies.